# Printing only the first character of an array

Tags: c

```
int
cycle(n) {
    char *s3 = "Different";
    int i, length;
    length = strlen(s3)
    printf("%s\n", s3);
    for (i=0; i<length; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", &s3[i]);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to print out one character at a time on each newline however the output looks like this -

```
C: Different   
C: ifferent
C: fferent
ect.
```

How do I make it just output one character at a time? Example (C: D, C:i, C:f, ect.)

Comment: `%c`, not `%s`, and don't pass the address.

Comment: As an alternative to `%c`, you could use `%.1s` which would print at most one character (but not print anything if the character is a NUL `'\0'`, whereas `%c` will print the NUL if told to do so).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change:

```
printf("%s\n", &s3[i]);
```

to

```
printf("%c\n", s3[i]);
```

The former prints a `string` while the latter prints a `char`.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s3); i++) {
  printf("%c\n", s3[i]);
}
```